# AXIS 1.5.3 Date Formatting Issue

Tags: apache-axis

In WSDL I have the following format:

When I generate the STUB (using Axis2 1.5.3), the generated stub (ADB
Data Binding) has the following source code :

public void setUSER_ACT_STRDT_TypeDef(Date param)
{

if (ConverterUtil.convertToString(param).matches("\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"))
  {

this.localUSER_ACT_STRDT_TypeDef=param;
  } 
  else 
  {
    throw new java.lang.RuntimeException();
  }
}

This method always throws RuntimeException because the
ConverterUtil.convertToString() method returns a String in a different
format than "yyyy-mm-dd".
It returns the date by appending +5.30 as 2011-03-21+05:30.